# Elasticsearch can not filter by datetime range

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

This might be a silly question but I could not manage to filter elasticsearch indexes by a datetime field. I must be missing something.

This is the mapping:

```
"created_at": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
},
```

This is what I got:

```
{
    "_index": "myindex",
    "_type": "myindextype",
    "_id": "21c",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "code": "21c",
      "name": "hello",
      ...
      "created_at": "2015-04-30T13:10:50.107769Z"
    }
 },
```

With this query:

```
"query": {
  "filtered": {
    "query": {},
    "filter": {
      "range": {
        "created_at": {
          "gte": "2015-05-02T13:10:50.107769Z"
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
}}}}}
```

I would expect to filter out the entry above. But it returns nothing.

Is there a problem with time format? Because it is directly coming from Django Rest Framework's [serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield). They claim that it is ISO 8601 format and elasticsearch claims the [same](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateOptionalTimeParser--).

I would also like to filter them out by a simpler date like "2015-05-02".

I am stuck. Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** It does not matter whatever i write into the range filter. It always return all the entries.

Answer (score 1):

This worked. I tried a lot of different things and lost my way at some point.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "created_at": {
            "gte": "2015-05-02"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```